# Trying to pull properties from another class in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, gps

I am completely new to iOS development so I may be doing this wrong but I have a class I am using to get coordinate gps data that I want to have as a generic class I can reuse in lots of apps. My problem is getting the data from the gps to properly display in other apps.

Here is my header file for the GPS class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationAwareness : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property(copy) NSString *longitude;
@property(copy) NSString *latitude;

@end
```

And here is the implementation:

```
#import "LocationAwareness.h"

@implementation LocationAwareness
@synthesize longitude;
@synthesize latitude;


- (id)init {

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    // Stops updating location if data has been updated within 10 minutes
    if ( abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 600) {

        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        float latitudedata = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", latitudedata];

        float logitudedata = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", logitudedata];

    }
}

@end
```

Now I can't seem to find anywhere that tells me how to get the latitude or longitude properties in another project. I have the header imported and have tried to store LocationAwareness.latitude into a variable that I can use but everything I store it in ends up blank. When I start my main class and aloc init a locationawareness object the gps fires up so I think its working but I don't seem to know enough about how this works to get everything in order. I've been searching the internet for hours. Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to know what is going on without seeing how you are implementing all this. As a reality check, perhaps try putting a log statement in the `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:` function so you are sure that there are values to get. In other word: ` NSLog(@"longitude: %@", longitude);`

Comment: Maybe I should say I want to know what a simple import and print to screen would look like. I know how to work with IBOulets and all that but I honestly have no idea how to make a property cross from one class to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this may or may not be causing the problem (it's quite likely), but a major problem is your init method.

The beginning should be:

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Do your initializing as you did above.
}
return self;
```

**edit:**
I added your code with my update to a project and it works well.
In order to use this, you should do something like the following:

```
LocationAwareness *loc = [[LocationAwareness alloc] init];

// Give it some time to start updating the current location and then
// in a different function:
NSLog(@"%@", loc.latitude);
```

**EDIT 2**
Wherever you are using this, you will want to declare a property which stores it so that you can create it once and reference it many times.  To do that, use the following code:

In the header for the object where you want to use this object, add this with the other properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) LocationAwareness *location;
```

Then, towards the top of your implementation file (.m file) you should see other @synthesize lines, add this one:

```
@synthesize location;
```

Then, create the actual location instance that you want to use as per the example above:

```
self.location = [[LocationAwareness alloc] init];
```

Now give it some time to figure out your location and start providing updates.  Then you can print the location like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.location.latitude);
```

Comment: Yeah I also should have mentioned I didn't know if the init is the proper thing to do there?

Comment: Yes, but if you don't call super, none of the classes that you inherit from (including NSObject) get initialized.  This will cause all kinds of crazy errors!

Comment: like this? 
    - (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy =      kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
    }

Comment: The tutorial I was following was for a viewcontroller but I wanted to change it

Comment: hmm tried your second code block in a brand new project in the viewdidload function noting came up in nslog:
2012-04-03 20:08:56.794 ClassTest[58569:c07] (null)
any ideas? maybe I have header wrong?

Comment: don't know what that is so probably not :P

Comment: Oh boy, my suggestion (if you are running 5.0+) is to enable it by selecting `Use Automatic Reference Counting` when you create your project.  Otherwise, you **really** need to read Apple's memory management guide, as there is a lot that you will need to change in order to get this to work.

Comment: hmmmm really? Actually think I did check that

Comment: Oh, I just figured out why.  That will be nil until the location has the chance to update.  I just added this to a project and it works well, but I saved the reference to a declared property (so that I had global access to it in my view controller) and then used a button to print the log line.  Works perfectly!

Comment: Do you know how to do this part?

Comment: Need to see the code to understand. Could you post it as an answer here?

Comment: what did you use for the nslog statement? I can't seem to pull value

I've tried:
NSLog(@"%@", location.latitude);
NSLog(@"%@", self.location.latitude);

Comment: Oops, sorry, I updated the answer.  It is `NSLog(@"%@", self.location.latitude);`  You have to give it time to determine your location though, so you probably want to have it called when you press a button or something like that!